# How can I unmarshal the following json into golang struct

Tags: json, go, nested, unmarshalling

How can I unmarshal the following json into golang struct

```json
{
  "VM": {
    "0": {
      "component": "A",
      "name": "hostname1",
      "hostname": "hostname1",
      "role": "NODE",
      "this": true,
      "type": "t1"
    },
    "1": {
      "component": "B",
      "name": "hostname2",
      "hostname": "hostname2",
      "role": "role2",
      "type": "t2"
    },
    "2": {
      "component": "C",
      "name": "hostname3",
      "hostname": "hostname3",
      "role": "role3",
      "type": "t3"
    },
    "n": { //this can go upto n levels
      "component": "N",
      "name": "hostnamen",
      "hostname": "hostnamen",
      "role": "rolen",
      "type": "tn"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, could you add what you have tried and what went wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This is a handy online resource to get you started: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

It does however get tripped up by defining specific struct fields instead of using a map - which appears the case here.

Striking a balance:

```
type Collection map[string][string]Component

type Component struct {
    Component string `json:"component"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Hostname  string `json:"hostname"`
    Role      string `json:"role"`
    This      bool   `json:"this"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
}
```

If your output always has a `"VM"` key at the top-level, then the `Collection` type could be flattened to something like:

```
type Collection struct {
    VM map[string]Component `json:"VM"`
}
// Component def stays the same
```

If you're confident the component indices will always be numeric, this may work too:

```
type Collection struct {
    VM map[int]Component `json:"VM"` // index by `int` instead of `string`
}
```

---

PlayGround example: https://play.golang.org/p/ewHnlq8h1Vc

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks @colm.anseo

Comment: @KetakiAggarwal If it works, please mark the answer as accepted.